# How to calculate Hamiltonian when Lagrangian has higher order derivatives?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

If we have a Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$ for a scalar field $\phi$ depending on $\phi$, $\partial _{\mu} \phi$, and $\partial _{\mu} \partial _{\nu} \phi$, what is the Hamiltonian? Additionally, what do Hamilton's equations become?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/382402/2451